# How can I find the category ID for category that has its own template on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to alphabetize all the posts in a category in WordPress. Instead of having the category in the *Categories* section of *Posts*, this category has a specific template and therefore does not display in the *Categories* section.

I have some PHP code that I hope will alphabetize posts in that category, however I need the category `ID`, which I can't find. Any help with how to find this category `ID` would be appreciated. If any other information is necessary to help, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and **post what you've tried** with a clear explanation of what **isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. I suggest reading [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

if I get your thinking, then go to all categories, hover on category "Edit" and you see on the browser link the `tag_ID` and thats the ID for your category
[image]

Comment: That was what I tried first, but due to the fact that this category has it's own template, it does not show up on the categories list under posts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the categories programmatically then I suggest you check out `get_the_category()`. This function returns all categories, and you can iterate through them to check for the category in question.

**Show the First Category Name Only**

```
$categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
}
```

For more information, check out the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/).

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm not looking to display anything at the moment, I'm just looking to find out what the category ID is in order to place it into my php code.However, I may be misunderstanding your response, in which case please let me know.

Comment: With the code in question you will be able to iterate through all the categories and get their Names and their ID's so that you'll know which ID is which and in other words be able to get your desired ID.